# Game of life, adding endless field

Tags: python, pygame

I have one question. I was doing game in pygame "game of life". I have one aim. I don't know how to add endless field to my game. can you help me, please? adding, sorry - my english is very bad(. i want to add endless field to my game. Stack overflow says me to add some txt. i don't know why

```
import pygame
import copy

class GameLife:
    def __init__(self, width, height, left=10, top=10, cell_size=30):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.board = [[0] * width for _ in range(height)]
        self.set_view(left, top, cell_size)
        self.pause = True
        self.speed = 10
        self.tick = 0
    def set_view(self, left, top, cell_size):
        self.left = left
        self.top = top
        self.cell_size = cell_size

    def get_cell(self, pos):
        if 0 < pos[0] - self.left < self.width * self.cell_size and 0 < pos[1] - self.top < self.height * self.cell_size:
            return (pos[0] - self.left) // self.cell_size, (pos[1] - self.top) // self.cell_size
        return None

    def on_click(self, cell):
        self.board[cell[1]][cell[0]] = (self.board[cell[1]][cell[0]] + 1) % 2

    def get_click(self, mouse_pos):
        cell = self.get_cell(mouse_pos)
        if cell and self.pause:
            self.on_click(cell)

    def render(self, scr):
        for x in range(self.width):
            for y in range(self.height):
                pygame.draw.rect(scr, 'white',
                                 (x * self.cell_size + self.left, y * self.cell_size + self.top,
                                  self.cell_size, self.cell_size), 1)
                if self.board[y][x]:
                    pygame.draw.rect(scr, pygame.Color('green'),
                                     (x * self.cell_size + self.left + 1, y * self.cell_size + self.top + 1,
                                    self.cell_size - 2, self.cell_size - 2))

    def change_status_pause(self):
        self.pause = not self.pause

    def next_move(self):
        if not self.pause and self.speed == self.tick:
            neighbors = [[0]*self.width for _ in range(self.height)]
            newboard = [[0] * self.width for _ in range(self.height)]
            for x in range(self.width):
                for y in range(self.height):
                    amount_neighbors = 0
                    for xx in range(x -1, x + 2):
                        for yy in range(y-1, y + 2):
                            if 0 < xx < self.width and 0 < yy < self.height and self.board[yy][xx]:
                                amount_neighbors += 1
                    neighbors[y][x] = amount_neighbors - self.board[y][x]
                    if neighbors[y][x] == 3 or neighbors[y][x] == 2 and self.board[y][x]:
                        newboard[y][x] = 1
            self.board = copy.deepcopy(newboard)

    def addtick(self):
        self.tick += 1
        if self.tick > self.speed:
            self.tick = 0


pygame.init()
size = width, height = 820, 420
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
cell_size = 20
top, left = 20, 10
board = GameLife((width - left * 2) // cell_size, (height - 2 * top) // cell_size, left, top, cell_size)
clock  = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            board.get_click(event.pos)
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            board.change_status_pause()
    board.next_move()
    board.addtick()
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    board.render(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(50)
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "endless" field ?

Comment: Here we will be helped by unrolling the torus on a plane: when a cell "disappears" on the right of the field, it often appears on the left, when it "disappears" from above, it appears at the bottom of the field, etc.

Comment: did you understand me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, there is only one condition you need to change. Use the `%` (modulo) operator to compute the remainder of an integer division:

<s>`if 0 < xx < self.width and 0 < yy < self.height and self.board[yy][xx]:`</s>

```py
if self.board[yy % self.height][xx % self.width]:
```

To explain the behavior:

- if `0 <= yy < self.height`, then the result of `yy % self.height` is `yy`.
- if `yy == -1`, then the result of `yy % self.height` is `self.height-1`
- if `yy == self.height`, then the result of `yy % self.height` is `0`

[image]